# Authentication for a web page via browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working on a Laravel project right now. I have a route www.website.com/auth/register. All I want is that when a hits this page, he should be asked for some credentials. If he inputs incorrect credentials, then he should not be able to see the registration page.

I have seen some web pages ask for authentication before we can see them. How is that achieved? I suppose those credentials are handled on the client side by the browser. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're talking about the [`BASIC Authentication method`](http://unixpapa.com/auth/basic.html), which exchanges credentials in plain text and is configured at the Web Server level.

Also, see this: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/988/is-basic-auth-secure-if-done-over-https

http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/security#http-basic-authentication